# Data analyse with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, analytics

Hello I have a dataframe of two columns (Id, Review Text) I need to group the dataframe based on id, and count how many times the words (cheap or light) have appeared in reviewText .
How can I do that?

Comment: do not be discouraged. You have a asked a theoretical question. People on the forum volunteer to help others. Its easier to help wen someone gives you a sample of the data and a sample of what they expect plus what they have tried to do. Are you happy to review the following and ask your question again? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce a dataframe based on the details you have mentioned.

Creation of dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id", "reviewText"])
```

Assigning dummy values to dataframe:

```
df["id"] = [1,1,3]
df["reviewText"] = ["Cheap boy", "Light dead", "Green wood"]
```

Creating new column "**check**" which will be True if "Cheap" or "Light" is present in "**reviewText**" otherwise False.

```
df['check'] = (df.reviewText.str.contains("Cheap")) | (df.reviewText.str.contains("Light"))
```

Then, doing the groupby:

```
df.groupby("id")["check"].value_counts()
```

Comment: can you tell me how i can just output the max of it  ؟

Comment: Just replace value_counts with max : df.groupby("id")["check"].max()